# Image size for BannerBitmap property in Windows Installer

Tags: windows-installer

I'm working on a quick setup program in Visual Studio and wanted to change the banner bitmap. Anyone know off-hand what the ideal (or the required) dimensions are for the new banner image? Thanks.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Found it on MSDN docs for [`BannerBitmap` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kbk77sf(v=vs.100).aspx):

> For best results, you should use a bitmap with dimensions of 500 pixels wide by 70 pixels high.

Comment: Thanks for this answer/question!  I had to create a banner image using these dimensions and my manually obtained dimensions were off in width by 5 px.  Thanks again!

Shane

Comment: From [John](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1100957/john) - also it needs to be a JPG or a BMP and RGB

Comment: @KyleMit I have successfully used a PNG file too, with adequate transparency. You just need to select All files in the file browser rather than Image files.

Comment: While the documentation states that the dimensions should be 500x70, I'm finding that 500x69 instead actually displays the image properly without stretching.